Conflicting probabilities for paths on a grid
Consider a $2 \times 2$ grid. Starting from $(0,0)$, move one unit up or right with equal probability until you reach position $(2,2)$. A given path can be described as a sequence, e.g., UURR.
The probability that after two step the path is on point $(2,0)$ is given by $1/4$ since there are $4$ possibilities. If the path is consider as a whole, then since there are $6$ total paths, there is a $1/6$ probability that a path crosses $(2,0)$.
My question is how these two results can be compatible? If, after two steps, $1/4$ of the time the path crosses $(2,0)$, then since the behavior of the path afterward should be irrelevant, I would expect this to be the overall probability. However, the latter result suggests that this is not the case.
Which result is correct? If a simulation was run, what percentage of the time would the path cross $(2,0)$?

Not sure what you mean by "equal probability" here.  From several nodes, only one direction is possible.  Maybe better to say each combination of ${R,R, U, U}$ is equally probable.

But that's the answer to your question.  If you meant that each of the $6$ paths is equally probable, then the desired probability is $\frac 16$.  If you meant "each path is a coin toss unless you have run out of room", then the paths are not equally probable.  It's up to you you to say which of those you meant (or, if you meant some third option, you shoudl say what it is).

If at each step you move one unit up or right with equal probability, then there is a probability $\frac{10}{16}$ that you never reach $(2,2)$ and a probability $\frac{6}{16}$ that you do reach $(2,2)$.  The unconditioned probability of reaching $(2,0)$ is $\frac{1}{4}$, but conditioned on eventually reaching $(2,2)$ it is $\frac{\frac14 \times \frac14}{\frac6{16}}$.

To clarify:  I assumed that our traveler was stuck on the $2\times 2$ grid you mentioned at the start.  There is, therefore, no chance of following any other that the $6$ paths that take you to $(2,2)$.  If I understood that incorrectly, please say so.

Can you please include a drawing of the grid? First you mention a 2x2 grid, but then you mention moving from (0,0) to (2,2) with a path like UURR, which implies at least a 3x3 grid.

Why do you think the six paths are equally likely? They would be if the path were directed by shuffling a deck of four cards labeled U, U, R, R, but you proposed a very different mechanism.

@Stef  It would be great if the OP would clarify a few of the ambiguous parts of this question...   That said, I think the ambiguity you are citing is the usual Fencepost problem.  That is to say, are we looking at side length or number of lattice points?  The interval from $(0,0)$ to $(2,0)$ is $2$ units long, but it contains $3$ lattice points.   Anyway, that's how I interpreted it.  If the OP returns, they can clarify their intent.

@dk30  I fear your post might soon be closed, as you have not clarified any of the ambiguities raised in the comments.  That would be a pity, it seems to me, as I think there may be real content in your question, whether you meant to ask about partially constrained motion (as in my posted solution) or if you meant to ask about conditional probabilities as some of the commenters have suggested.  Please edit your post to resolve these issues.

@lulu I think the ambiguities are inherently part of the question and of the apparent "paradox" raised by the OP's, just like the ambiguity is inherently part of Bertrand's paradox. Sadly, both answers have chosen one interpretation each of the probability space described in the question, and answered the question under that interpretation only; I think a more complete answer would be listing explicitly the different possible interpretations and showing how they lead to distinct probabilities.

@Stef  Well, The OP knows if they intended the traveler to be confined to the $2\times 2$ grid or not.  I think that's the big ambiguity.

To stress, as there seems to be some confusion:  I am interpreting the problem as restricted to the $2\times 2$ grid mentioned at the start of the question. Thus,  there is no doubt that you reach $(2,2)$ and you must take one of $6$ paths to get there. The only uncertainty i see is the probability of the possible choices.
To summarize the discussion in the comments:  The problem is that the way you you defined the probability distribution is not clear.
there are, as you say, $6$ paths you might follow:
$$\{RRUU, RURU, RUUR, UURR, URUR, URRU\}$$
You might have said (or you might have meant):  These paths are equally likely.  In that case, the answer you want is $\frac 16$.
What you did say is that $R,U$ are equally probable but it's not clear what that means.  For any node with a $2$ as a coordinate, the remaining moves are all forced, certainly not "equally probable".  One possible interpretation is that, if you can go either up or right, then it is a $\frac 12$ chance of each, and if your moves are constrained, you do what you have to.  That makes sense, but in that case the paths are not equally probable.  Indeed, $\{RRUU, UURR\}$ each have probability $\frac 14$, while all the other paths have probability $\frac 18$ (as only the final move is constrained).  Thus, with this interpretation, the probability you want is indeed $\frac 14$.

Alternative explanation:
If you are given, that you are going to travel from $~(0,0)~$ to $~(2,2),~$ then as you indicated, there are $~\displaystyle \binom{4}{2} = 6~$ possible paths, each of which is equally likely, only one of which crosses $~(2,0).~$
Then, as you further indicate, starting from $~(0,0),~$ and only traveling upwards or to the right, the probability of crossing $~(2,0)~$ is $~\dfrac{1}{4}.$

So far, so good, except that it leaves an anomaly: $~\dfrac{1}{6} \neq \dfrac{1}{4}.$
Assume that each navigation step is either upwards or to the right.
Let event $~A~$ denote the event that you travel from $~(0,0)~$ to $~(2,0).~$
Let event $~B~$ denote the event that you travel from $~(0,0)~$ to $~(2,2).~$
What the analysis in your posted question has proven is that:

$p( ~A ~) = \dfrac{1}{4}.$

$p( ~A ~| ~B ~) = \dfrac{1}{6}.$ 
That is, the probability of event $~A~$ occurring, under the assumption that event $~B~$ occurs is $~\dfrac{1}{6}.~$


Therefore, events $~A~$ and $~B~$ are not independent events, and if you are given that event $~B~$ has occurred, then this lowers the probability that event $~A~$ has occurred.
So, the entire problem reduces to providing some intuitive explanation for why the occurrence of the event $~B~$ would lower the probability of event $~A~$ occurring.
This is subtle.  On the one hand, if you know that if (for example) $~(1,3)~$ was reached, this would prevent $~(2,0)~$ from being reached.  Further, the fact that $~(2,2)~$ was reached indicates that $~(1,3)~$ was not reached.
So, from the perspective of the last paragraph, the fact that event $~B~$ has occurred has actually had a good effect on whether event $~A~$ occurred.

On the other hand, if you reach $~(3,0),~$ which guarantees that you reached $~(2,0),~$ then you could not have reached $~(2,2).~$
So, from the perspective of the last paragraph, the fact that event $~B~$ has occurred has actually had a bad effect on whether event $~A~$ occurred.
Apparently, you have two competing forces, and the bad effect outweighs the good effect, so that $~p( ~A ~| ~B ~) < p(A).$

I should emphasize that (in a sense) the formal math presented at the start of my answer is what counts.  The subsequent informal rhetoric is simply a reasonable try at stretching intuition to accommodate the mathematically proven result.
